# How can I remove mailed-by and signed-by tag from email

Tags: php, email

I am using php-mailer to send email.
The mail goes succesfully however in each email I get "mailed-by: gamil.com" and signed-by:  "gmail.com" in mail header.

How can I remove mailed-by and signed-by tag from email ?
Here is my code

```
require_once('././php_mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$body = html($msg);
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
try {
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // sets the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 465;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username   = 'nabina.smartmobe@gmail.com'; // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password   = '******';        // SMTP account password
    $mail->AddAddress($to, 'Nabina');

    $mail->SetFrom('no-reply@nayacinema.com.np', 'no-reply@nayacinema.com.np');
    $mail->AddReplyTo('no-reply@nayacinema.com.np', 'no-reply@nayacinema.com.np');
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject ='NayaCinema: '.$subject;
    $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    if($attachment){
    $mail->AddAttachment($attachment);
    }
    if($mail->Send()){
        //echo 'sent'; die;
        return true;
    }else{
        //echo ' not sent'; die;
        return false;
    }
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
     echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. Please read this article and try to improve your question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Set the `Sender` property. That should remove those headers.